# How to get http response from lumen API asynchronously

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lumen

Lumen is sending response to the client side according to the order of requests. It is holding  next response until previous response completes. I need to make it asynchronously

- **Laravel Lumen Routing Code:**

```
$router->get('waist-xxxxxxx/v20/', ['uses' => 'DemoController@fnDemoFunction']);
$router->get('waist-xxxxxxx/v20/{serverSideRowUuid}', ['uses' => 'DemoController@fnDemoFunction']);
$router->post('waist-xxxxxxx/v20/', ['uses' => 'DemoController@create']);
$router->put('waist-xxxxxxx/v20/{serverSideRowUuid}', ['uses' => 'DemoController@update']);
$router->options('waist-xxxxxxx/v20', function () {
    return response('OK', \Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Connection', 'keep-alive');
});
$router->options('waist-xxxxxxx/v20/{serverSideRowUuid}', function () {
    return response('OK', \Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Connection', 'keep-alive');
});
```

- **Vue.js App code for API calling:**

```
export default {
    methods: {
     async mxGetDataFromDb() {
     /*                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       TODO: Need to restrict the load to current data                                                                                                                                                   
       api is vuex-orm-axios plugin function                                                                                                                                                                
       When using json-server backend the code is:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     */
     console.log('reminders req sent')
     const proRemsFromDB = await clientSideTable.api().get(clientSideTable.apiUrl)
     console.log('reminders recd')
     if (proRemsFromDB.ok) {
     }
   },
 },
}
```

Here is a screenshot for better understanding: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwIDb.png)

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using `php artisan serve` to test with.

This command utilizes [the built-in PHP development server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). It's a great tool, but it can only handle one request at a time:

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

In general, while `php artisan serve` is great for quick testing, you'll want to set up something like [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead) or some other more robust development environment long-term.